# How to filter one combo-box collection depending on the selected item of another?

Tags: php, mysql

On php page in a form, one combo-box has list of customers from a MySQL table `customer.` Another combo-box contains `invoiceno` fields from the `invoice` table, respective to customer records.

I want to select a customer from the first combo box and filter invoiceno from the second one according to the customer. Can anyone help me accomplish this?

For example, if I select customer1, the second combo box should show all `invoiceno` respective to the customer1. I want to do this without refreshing, reloading, or POSTing the page. If I get the first selection in a php variable `$customer`, it's enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is your friend:

1. Capture onchange event of the first combo box
2. Then send the value of the selected item via AJAX to your PHP script
3. Your PHP script loads the corresponding values from the databases and returns them (for example in JSON format)
4. And finally you display/insert the returned data via JavaScript.

Pseudo code:

JavaScript:

```
function displayData(json)
{
  // Do something
}
document.getElementById("your-combobox").addEventListener("change", function()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
      displayData( JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) ); // Call displayData with the JSON
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "your-script.php?combobox1="+encodeURIComponent(this.value));
  xhr.send(null); // Send AJAX request
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['combobox1'])) exit('{}');

$data = GetDataFromDB_AsArray();

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```